# Java AccesControlException

Tags: java, security, exception, accesscontrolexception

When I run my Java program, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.security.policy" "read")
```

To fix this, I was told to add this to the Java policy:

```
grant codeBase "file:C:/User/user/Documents/NetBeansProjects/-" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

That did not work, though. How can I fix this?

Comment: in your policyfile, do you actually have `file:C:/User/user/Documents/NetBeansProjects/-` or is that `-` a placeholder to what's actually there for privacy reasons?

Comment: That "-" is, according to my source, a way to say: all. Like "*" in Linux

Comment: Not as far as I know, have a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/security/policy.html), afaik you should use the usual wildcards, and they should point to where your code runs from.  In the NetBeans execution/debugger context that's the build subdirectory of your project's directory which should be a subdir of NetbeansProjects

Comment: *"I was told to add this to the Java policy:"*  **Who** told you that?  What type of app. is it?  Plain desktop app., applet, JWS app., web app. ..?